# cardinality of sets intersections

Tags: discrete-mathematics, cardinals

Given that:

$$| A \cap \mathbb{R}| = |\mathbb{R}| $$ 
$$| B \cap \mathbb{R}| = |\mathbb{N}| $$

Can we say that: 
$$|A| = |\mathbb{R}|$$
$$|B| = |\mathbb{N}|$$
?

If not, can we say something for sure about the cardinality of either $A$ or $B$?

Comment: What do you think? What about $B=\mathbb{Z}$ or $B=\mathbb{R}?$

Comment: What about $A := \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}) \cup \mathbb{R}$, then $|A| \geq |\mathbb{R}|$

Comment: Well, when you put it this way...It seems obvious now, thank you guys, you can post it as an answer

Comment: What if $B = \mathbb N \cup (\mathbb C \setminus \mathbb R)$.